# Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals and print outcome

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I study swift about `*Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals*`.
I know that the `optional` is value to check whether it contains value or nil. 
In the bottom of code, I declare `Implicitly Unwrapped Optionals`. But, it print `optional(123)`. What's the problem?

```
if let state03:Int! = Int("123")
{
    print("State03 Ok")
    let check = state03
    print("\(check!)")
    print("\(state03)")
}
else
{
    print("nil")
}
```

In the case of `optional(?)`, I understand the outcome.(optional(123))
But above case, I don't know why the outcome is `optional`.

Comment: you declared it as an Optional. try if let state03 = Int("123") {..} In your if let state03: Int! = Int("a") {} else { // you never rich this } because the binding will always success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don´t know if the `cast` from the `string` to `Int("123")` is `nil` or not, that is why it´s an `optional` and it prints out `optional(123)`. If you´re sure that `Int("123")` will succeed you can and an `!`.

```
if let state03:Int! = Int("123")!
```

Or you could just declare your `state03` without the `Int!` and just use `Int`.

```
if let state03:Int = Int("123")
```

Both solution works.

Comment: @user2893289 Thank you very much!! If the value certainty exists, I can use !. Do I understand correctly???

Answer (score 0):

**Implicitly unwrapped optionals** are also optionals. The difference from other optionals is that they are assumed to always hold a value instead of being given compile-time errors that they may be `nil`.

> Implicitly unwrapped optionals are useful when an optional’s value is confirmed to exist immediately after the optional is first defined and can definitely be assumed to exist at every point thereafter.

Therefore, you should consider it as a normal optional, with the exception that it will not give you errors during compilation, because it is assumed to hold a value. However if it was used when it had a `nil` value, it will still give runtime errors.

In your code, define `state03` as `Int` not as `Int!`.

The `if let` statement, will handle the output of `Int("123")` being `nil`. If it was not `nil`, it will execute the if block. If it was `nil`, it will execute the else block.

Comment: implicit unwrapped optional can hold nil value without any trouble! 
'var k: Int! = nil
if k == nil {
    print("nil")
}' You can reassign it 'k = 1 // now the value is 1'

Comment: I know that. What I meant was that assigning them to `nil` AFTER they have been given a value was not allowed, or that's what I thought. I tried it and it worked, so I updated my answer.

Comment: what you updated, is not true. you can reassign the value as you want. if nil is not valid in your code and you are going to use it (as non-optional), you app will crash. you are still able to check if you implicitly unwrapped variable is nil, or not, to avoid this. the compiler use an implicitly unwrapped variable as 'normal' variable

Comment: And that is what my answer says.